# Programmatically answer an incoming phone call on iPhone

Tags: iphone, phone-call

How can we answer an incoming voice call programmatically using Objective-C on an iPhone?

Comment: I think answering a phonecall should always be the choice of the owner of the phone. When it comes to privacy this is not allowed.

Comment: I think it's not possible to answering the phone call programmatically..Apple will not allow you to enter into user privacy details...

Comment: I do not understand what has this question been downvoted.

Answer (score 7):

You can't. You don't even got a notification or whatever that there's an incoming call. All you can do is ask the iPhone to *make* a call (via the `tel:` URI scheme) but you won't even know whether the phone actually did dial the number.

That is on purpose for privacy/anti-malware reasons, BTW.

Comment: This answer is partially true. ios sdk has CoreTelephony framework which lets our applications to receive notifications if there is any change in call state. I mean, our app is notified when there is an incoming call, when we receive the call, when we terminate the call, when we make a call etc.